# Doctrine and DQL with object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I learn symfony and doctrine. I have tables: User, products and payments. I would like get all in array with relationships doctrine. Ex: product.getPackagesId.name in twig.

```
User: ID, NAME etc.
products: ID, USER_ID(relationships), PACKAGES_ID(relationships)...
payments: ID,  PRODUCTS_ID(relationships)...
```

Now: I have id user (getID()), want get products, but after I have problem with payments.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` JOIN payments ON products.id=payments.products_id where products.user_id=:user");
    $statement->bindValue('user', $userID);
    $statement->execute();
    $products = $statement->fetchAll();


[0] => Array //name table
    (
        [id] => 3 //products
        [user_id] => 1 //products
        [packages_id] => 1 //products
        [status] => 0 //products
        [mail] =>  //products
        [data_trial] =>  //payments
        [products_id] => 3 //payments
        [data_order] => 2014-08-05 14:07:49 //payments
        [data_payment] => //payments
        [data_billing] => 30 //payments
        [data_expiration] =>  //payments
    )
```

I have all records. It nice, but I have packages_id, it's not object in doctrine. I can't use relationships. I tried createQuery, but returns 2 object (for products and payments)

```
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT p, c FROM MySaleBundle:Products p
        JOIN MySaleBundle:Payments c
        WHERE p.id=c.products_id and p.user_id = :id'
    )->setParameter('id', $userID);
    $products= $query->getArrayResult();
```

Returns:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [status] => 
        [mail] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [data_order] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-08-05 14:07:49.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/Warsaw
            )

        [data_payment] => 
        [data_billing] => 30
        [data_expiration] => 
    )
```

Comment: You are not using DQL, but SQL directly, since you are using Doctrine DBAL not Doctrine ORM. I'm not sure if Doctrine ORM can do what you want, but you could have a look at the array hydration feature: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration

Comment: Ok. I edited the post. I added DQL. Where is mistake that returns 2 objects?

Comment: I think it's because you are explicitly selecting them "SELECT p, c FROM...". Keep in mind that this is not SQL. It should be something like "SELECT p FROM MySaleBundle:Products p JOIN p.payments pa WHERE p.user_id = :id". But still, I am not sure if Doctrine will fetch the payments for you.

Comment: See: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: Otherwise. Use: getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR) I have 1 object in prefix: [p_id] => 3, [c_data_payment] etc. But how use product.getPackagesId.name in twig? product.p_getPackagesId.name doesn't works.

Comment: Are you sure you want to get arrays as the result and not objects? If objects are fine, you wouldn't even need a JOIN (although it is good for performance). You could just use ->getResult(). Then you can access it like this: product.packages.name (I don't know for sure, since I don't know your model classes).

Comment: I want objects, but it bad returns. Look for my createQuery(), I get separate object: product and payment. I need mutual object, because I use in twig the loop for. Example: In database are 3 products and their payments. Query returns: 6 records. 3 product and 3 payments, I need 3 records: product and relationship payments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58828/discussion-between-viko-and-leif).